# com.springsource.org.hibernate maven artifact jar file download failed

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I added SpringSource repositories in my pom.xml as follows:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
        <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I tried to add all versions of it as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <!--
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <version>4.0.0.CR4</version>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        -->
    </dependency>
```

But all failed.

In Maven Dependencies, its jar didn't appear.

I checked .m2 directory and there were the only files as follows:

```
_maven.repositories
com.springsource.org.hibernate-4.1.0.Final.pom.lastUpdated
com.springsource.org.hibernate-4.1.0.Final.pom
com.springsource.org.hibernate-4.1.0.Final.pom.sha1
```

I tried to download after deleting the whole directory several times.

Suddenly it's working now.

What am I missing? What was my fault?

Comment: Perhaps network problems or the repository was temporarily down?

Comment: @Raghuram If there was any network problem or the server's downtime, how could .pom and .pom.sha1 files be downloaded?

Comment: Good point.  Perhaps only jars were getting/being blocked?

Comment: @Raghuram Why do public repositories like SpringSource block jar files not to be downloaded? I think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Raghuram BTW I've got the following message between successful downloads:
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Missing artifact org.hibernate:com.springsource.org.hibernate:jar:4.1.0.Final
 - ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:com.springsource.org.hibernate:jar:4.1.0.Final 
  from/to com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external): No 
  response received after 60000
As you mentioned, there must be sort of network problem.